# Save image path name from sdcard to Sqlite database

Tags: android

am having a little trouble here. i am trying to store and retrieve images from an sqlitedatabase by storing their image path name. the images are stored in the sdcard. I tried this code, but its not working.

saving image path:

```
 String filename = "/sdcard/barn.jpg"

ContentValues vals2 = new ContentValues(); //create content values and store it.
   vals.put(ImageDB.SHOW, filename);
   imagedb.tagImage(vals2);


public long tagImage(ContentValues val){
        Log.d(TAG,"tagged Images");
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, val);
    }
```

retrieving :

```
Cursor cursor = imagedb.retrieveTag(tag);

    /*method for retrieving*/

    public Cursor retrieveTag(String tag){
    String[] condition = {tag)};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, condition, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToNext();
        return cursor;
    }
```

The cursor is not returning anything and i sometimes get a CursorIndexOutofBoundsException.
Is this a correct way to save and retrieve from an sqlitedatabase or does the filename pose a problem for the sqlite database?.. How can i store it correctly?.. Thank you.

Comment: any better way to save it? i don't want to save the actual image in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting the root directory with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), harcoding "/sdcard/" may not work.

Comment: ok..remembered something like that. thanks! will give that a go!